# std::async always executes on the same thread my other cores are doing nothing

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, concurrency, future

I want to parallelism a number of task using `std::async`. Those task, lambdas, will modify an object. I know that it's up to the `std::async` implementation do decide how the task is handled. I also understand that with specifying `std::launch::async` I could "force" parallel execution.

What makes me wondering is, that despise all my other cores doing nothing, the implementation still decided to not run the task in parallel. I would absolutely be happy with serial execution but only if my other cores would be busy.

For me it's somehow takes away the sense compared to `std::thread` - especially if you still care about oversubscription. Is there a point is this behaviour I'm missing?

I'm doing the work in such a fashion, if that's relevant:

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> futs;
for(size_t i=0; i<someNumber; ++i)
    futs.emplace_back( std::async(std::launch::async, someLambda, i) );

for(auto& fut : futs)
    fut.get(); // they return nothing, but I need to make sure they have executed.
```

**Edit**:
The execution time with `std::launch::asyc` is about 1/4th compared to the default policy. I've 4 cores.
Here what library and gcc version I'm using:

```
$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
        libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
```

Comment: For how long (roughly) do the tasks run and what implementation are you using? I get a few different thread ids with both MSVC2015U3 and whatever [ideone](http://ideone.com/KVNHJD) is using.

Comment: The intention was to let the compiler pick something smart.  Not all compilers delivered.

Comment: GCC 6 changed this to default to `async`.